# Get "number of lines in a string" as a value in Geometry Nodes

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, text-object

[image]

I have this node setup that takes a string and divides them into lines by using the special characters node to replace space " " with a line break.

I wanted a numerical value of the number of lines this outputs. For example, if there are 4 lines, I want 4 as an output.

Is this possible? The line option in string to curves node is a field and I don't know how can I convert it into an integer that can be used anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could get it with this node tree:

[image]